# Intellij class Import being added to object not the top of class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've just started a new IntelliJ project. When I try and import a java class with the IntelliJ import shortcut, the import is being added to the object and not to the top of the class like it normally would.

Where in the settings can I change this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other classes in that package that are named `Path` or `Paths`?

Comment: No, just the one `Main` class.

Comment: So you press Alt+Enter and choose import class ?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: In `Preferences/Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java` have you ticked the box for "Use fully qualified class names"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See `Preferences/Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java` if this option ...

- Use fully qualified class names

... is ticked then IntelliJ will always use fully qualified class names. If you disable this option then Intellij will include the import statement and refer to the class by its 'simple' name.

Here's a screenshot showing this configuration item:

[image]

Comment: in my case it was unchecked and this answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67740501/8430173

Answer (score 1):

If the accepted answer is not working for anyone, Try the below points too.

- Check whether the class file is in correct package and resolve if there is any issues in the class file.
- Click **File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart** and Click **Invalidate and Restart** button, Once it restarted U'll be able to import properly.

Comment: worked for me! This solution solves almost every problem in IntelliJ :))

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue with my custom / generated(protobuf) java packages.

**Solution** (TDLR)

- Whenever you face this issue, just check the package or class that getting imported doesn't have any error(red marking).
- If so try to fix that.
  I was having an `issue with package naming and its actual location`. By **generated-sources** `-> Right Click -> Mark Directory As -> Sources Root` corrected my issue.
- Check whether **generated-sources** or **folder under the generated sources** need to mark us Sources Root.

**My issue was with generated java files (Adding this just to help someone else with same issue)**

Intellij shows red mark for Import with wildchar(import pkg1.subpkg1.*;). Like editor was unable to recognizing 'import all' under a package.

But direct import to the inner package was fine.

On top of that an resolving issue with `import class` add full package to the Class itself, instead of adding import statement on top the java file.

This issue didn't affect the code compilation, only in editor it was showing red mark.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with importing generated classes from target folder.
And it fixed by creating the same package from target in the main path.

So if you have imported class in
`target/generated-sources/org/example/dto/Import.class`

You need to create same package in the main path:
`src/main/org/example/dto`

It can be empty. But now Intellij will put imports to the top of the class.